# Golang REST API ответ ошибки

Tags: http, golang, api, rest, handle

Идеологически правильный возврат ошибки клиенту REST API

К примеру простой REST API:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/go-chi/render"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func main() {
    r := http.HandlerFunc(ping)
    srv := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":3000",
        Handler: r,
    }
    fmt.Println("server started")
    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func ping(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    i, err := convert("a")
    if err != nil {
        SendErrorJSON(w, r, 500, err, "cannot ping", 900)
        return
    }
    render.JSON(w, r, i)
}

func convert(value string) (int, error) {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(value)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, errors.Wrap(err, "error stctonv atoi")
    }
    return i, nil
}

func sendError(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, httpStatusCode int, err error, details string, errCode int) {
    log.Printf("[WARN] status: %v error: %v detalis: %v errorcode: %v", httpStatusCode, err.Error(), details, errCode)
    render.Status(r, httpStatusCode)
    render.JSON(w, r, map[string]interface{}{"error": err.Error(), "detalis": details, "errorcode": errCode})
}
```

При конвертирование `string` в `int` произойдет ожидаемая ошибка
и клиенту вернется нечто такое:

```
{"code":900,"details":"cannot ping","error":"error stctonv atoi: strconv.Atoi: parsing \"d\": invalid syntax"}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет в данном примере правильно обработать ошибку (т.е. вернуть клиенту API), чтобы не показывать детали ошибки: 
`"error stctonv atoi: strconv.Atoi: parsing \"d\": invalid syntax"`

Понятно, что в данном примере можно просто не вывести её в `render.JSON()`, но какую стратегию обработки ошибок выбрать, когда ошибка идет из "глубины" проекта и с каждом уровнем обрастает контекстом?

Answer (score 1):

Входные данные от пользователя необходимо валидировать прежде, чем передавать их дальше. Если данные невалидны, то возвращать ответ с кодом 400 и описанием проблемы.

Внутренние ошибки сервера могут означать что есть ошибки в самом коде либо инфраструктурные проблемы. В любом случае пользователь не может повлиять на это извне и должен либо дождаться когда баг будет исправлен, либо когда разрешатся проблемы на уровне инфраструктуры. Поэтому считаю, что такие ошибки стоит логировать, добавлять мониторинги, но пользователю будет достаточно сообщения `500 Internal Error`.

Comment: Тоже к этому склоняюсь, но хотелось услышать опыт других разработчиков.